# Play button doesn't work after music is stopped with stop button

Tags: android, button, playback

I have two buttons that will start and stop a song, when i start the app I can play the song and then stop it again. However when i wanna start it again it doesn't work.

```
    final Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.start();
            play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in play.onclicklistner

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(Peshmerga.this, R.raw.sppeshmerga);
 mp.start();
```

add following to your stop.onclicklistner

```
 if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
   }
```

you need to create everytime you click play button .

Comment: Thanks this did the job! `mp = MediaPlayer.create(Peshmerga.this, R.raw.sppeshmerga);`in play.onclicklistener and `if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
   }` in stop.onclicklistener

Comment: sorry to bother you, but im having trouble with my onPause() method. after ive paused the music how do i resume it properly?

Comment: so do you have one more click for pause ? or talking about activity onpause(); ??

Comment: activity onPause `@Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  mp.pause();
 }` How to resume properly after this

Comment: did you override onResume();  ?

Comment: yes `@Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();
  
 }` When i put in mp.start() it starts the music automatically when the app starts

Comment: try this in onPause(); if(mp.isPlaying()){
    mp.pause();
} else {
    mp.start();
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59659/discussion-between-droidshout-and-dhwanik-gandhi).

Comment: still no luck, that still starts the song on app start and starts the song repeatedly when you click play

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to start again by play button. Add the following code above the `mp.start()` method:

```
mp.reset();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

I guess you have rest of things set properly and in stop button use the following:

```
if (mp != null) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've already tried that and the music wont even start the first time. The onclick works because it plays and stops the music the first time, however if I want to play it again it doesnt work. The buttons do hide and show but the music wont start.

Comment: That didnt help, and mp.prepare is not needed because "create" takes care of it? mp = MediaPlayer.create(Peshmerga.this, R.raw.sppeshmerga);

Comment: also mp.release() in stop button crashes the appp

Comment: Thanks @james but DhwanikGandhi was faster than you, thank you both. :)

Comment: @DroidShout I was busy with my work. But thanks for up vote. Recently some basterd accepted my answer and then removed that accepted that tag. But THANKS ONCE again. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @james I understand really, I appriciate your answer anyway. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Look at the state diagram image in the following link:

-----------------------------------------[android-mediaplayer-sample-code](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/android-mediaplayer-sample-code-walkthrough-on-intel-architecture)----------------------------------------------

[image]

```
mp.reset();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Play Button Click Listener:

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
       try{
           if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
               mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.test);
               mMediaPlayer.start();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e){
       }
    }
});
```

Stop Button Click Listener:

```
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                    mMediaPlayer = null;
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.test);
                }
            }
        });
```