# Android is hanging when I press button to play music in second time

Tags: android

I used these codes from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404731/play-button-doesnt-work-after-music-is-stoped-with-stop-button). They want to click on button to play music and then click again to stop playing. (in their comment they said it was worked for them but hanging for me)
It is work just for first time. I mean for first click the music is playing. for second click the music is stop but for third click the phone emulator show this error:

> unfortunately your program has stopped.

This is my code:

```
public MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRain);
        //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rain);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rain);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            //MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.soundFileName);
             //       mp.start();
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
                else {

                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onCreate initialize mp as :

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

The error is you are releasing the media player object mp, which destroys the object, call reset method instead of release.

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) 
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
            else {
              mp = MediaPlayer.create(LegalActivity.this, R.raw.free1);
                mp.start();      
            }
```

Comment: when I put mp.stop(); after stop the music then it can not play again. It dose not work. :(

Comment: updated answer and tested it in genymotion, its working fine. please have a look at the edited answer

Comment: yes. thank you. it works perfect. my problem is I define mp before on click but you first create it before on click then put value to mp before start. really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this below code for play and pause the music:

```
public MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRain);
        //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rain);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rain);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            //MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.soundFileName);
             //       mp.start();
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                }
                else {

                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: the error not occurred but after stop music , I click to play again. but not play music. nothing hear.

Comment: i have done some changes in above code please check that changes

Comment: thanks. but I want to play from start. not from pause. How can I do that?

Comment: when click on button at that time check mediaplayer is playing if playing then first do mediaplayer.stop(); then write mediaplayer.start(); i think it works.

Comment: if you mean something like this:=> if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                }
                else {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.start();
                }. I do than. but the button not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is an AUDIO activity that works fine and it allows you to upload songs with a spinner.

```
public class AUDIO extends Activity{

Spinner spCanciones;
Button btnRep,btnGra,btnParar;
File audios;
String cancionSelec;
String arquivoGravar;
private MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
private boolean pause;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);
    spCanciones=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spCanciones);
    btnGra=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGra);
    btnParar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnParar);
    btnRep=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRep);
    mediaplayer=new MediaPlayer();

    enlazarSpinner();

    //REPRODUCIR
    btnRep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reproducir();
        }
    });

    //PARAR
    btnParar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaplayer.isPlaying())
                mediaplayer.stop();
            pause=false;
        }
    });

    //GRABAR
    btnGra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            grabarAudio();
        }
    });
}


public void enlazarSpinner(){
    final ArrayList<String>songs=new ArrayList<>();
    audios=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"/AUDIO/");
    String [] play=audios.list();
    for (int i=0;i<play.length;i++)songs.add(play[i]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, songs);

    // Opcional: layout usuado para representar os datos no Spinner
    adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Enlace do adaptador co Spinner do Layout.
    spCanciones.setAdapter(adaptador);

    // Escoitador
    spCanciones.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            cancionSelec = songs.get(pos);
            Log.i("Cancion", cancionSelec);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }); // Fin da clase anónima
}


public void reproducir(){
    try {
        mediaplayer.reset();
        mediaplayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/AUDIO/"+cancionSelec);
        mediaplayer.prepare();
        mediaplayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("MULTIMEDIA",e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void grabarAudio(){
    String timeStamp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(
            new Date()).replaceAll(":", "").replaceAll("/", "_")
            .replaceAll(" ", "_");

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    arquivoGravar = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/AUDIO/"+ timeStamp + ".3gp";
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(32768);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000); // No emulador só 8000 coma
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(arquivoGravar);
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        mediaRecorder.reset();
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("GRAVANDO").setPositiveButton(
                    "PREME PARA PARAR",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mediaRecorder.stop();
                            mediaRecorder.release();
                            mediaRecorder = null;
                        }
                    });
    dialog.show();
    enlazarSpinner();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaplayer.pause();
        pause = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (pause) {
        mediaplayer.start();
        pause = false;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle estado) {
    estado.putBoolean("MEDIAPLAYER_PAUSE", pause);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(estado);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MEDIAPLAYER_PAUSE", false);
    pause = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MEDIAPLAYER_PAUSE");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) mediaplayer.stop();

    if (mediaplayer != null) mediaplayer.release();
    mediaplayer = null;

}
}
```